# Find coordinates of the lines detected by the Canny edge detector

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have been trying to extract coordinates of the lines present in the image.

I tried canny edge detection to detect the lines. They got successfully detected.

How can I find the coordinates of these lines ?

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4mx8.png)

[image: Result]

```py
    img = cv2.imread('/content/sample_data/dilatedtest1.png',0)
    edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200)
    
    plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(edges,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Canny finds edges, not lines. Each line in your image has two edges, your output should contain two parallel lines close together for each input line.

Answer (score 2):

`cv2.Canny` outputs a binary image. You can use `np.nonzero(edges)` or `np.where(edges != 0)` to get the coordinates :

```py
img = cv2.imread('/content/sample_data/dilatedtest1.png',0)
edges = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)

row_indexes, col_indexes = np.nonzero(edges)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you please guide me how to find the point of intersection of these lines? The parallel lines are intersecting with the second row in the image. I'm llooking to get the x,y coordinates for these points. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://www.mathopenref.com/coordintersection.html for example or search Google for similar explanations

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cv2.HoughLines()` to detect lines in your edge image. The lines are returned in parametric form: `(rho,theta)` pairs for which `rho = x * cos(theta) + y * sin(theta)`. The code below (taken from OpenCV's tutorial on using `cv2.HoughLines()`) shows how to get the pixel coordinates of two points in a line `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)`. Intersecting two lines is then easy since you have the lines as point pairs (search the web for line-line intersection).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('dave.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)

lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,200)
for rho,theta in lines[0]:
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)

cv2.imwrite('houghlines3.jpg',img)
```