# Getting the wire pixels/colors detected by using Canny Edge Detection

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have to loop through a horizontal row of pixels (like the vertical center of each wire). Where the edge image should have white at the start and end of each wire, and the pixels after a start and before an end. I wanted to code this for me to get the color of each wire. [Sample image of my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWE6S.jpg)

I have tried this code to get the column pixels

```
row_indexes, col_indexes = np.nonzero(edges)
print(row_indexes)
print(col_indexes)
```

but I don't get the output in the console:

```
[  0   0   1 ... 334 334 334]
[423 438 422 ... 466 480 502]
```

I wanted to get the color of each wire by using first the canny edge detection. Next I am having trouble with getting the x- position of that vertical line because the next thing I need to do is get a list of colors from left to right like

```
[Violet,Blue,Brown, etc...]
```

**Here's my code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image= cv2.imread('Template.jpg')
gray= cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5),0)
_, bin = cv2.threshold(gray,120,255,1) # inverted threshold (light obj on dark bg)
bin = cv2.dilate(bin, None)  # fill some holes
bin = cv2.dilate(bin, None)
bin = cv2.erode(bin, None)   # dilate made our shape larger, revert that
bin = cv2.erode(bin, None)
edges= cv2.Canny(gray, 50,200)

cv2.imshow("Image", original_image)
cv2.imshow("Grayscale", gray)
cv2.imshow("Edges", edges)
```

Comment: We need to see more code? Why do you need to do Canny edge detection. Why do you convert to grayscale?

Comment: @fmw42 I've included the code on my edited post. Well my first approach was manually setting the hsv range values to detect the wires however it's not that efficient to use as an approach and some has suggested that I can try edge detection to detect the wires.

Comment: What does your result look like?  What then are you trying to count?

Comment: Perhaps you should find contours of the wires and then do thinning to get the medial axis (center line).

Comment: @fmw42 my result is included in the post, the link at the end of the 1st paragraph.
So I just know that generally I have to use the:
rows = image.shape[0]
middle_row = image[rows//2]
- as my code to loop through a horizontal row of pixels (e.g. in the vertical center of the image). Though if I try to insert it with my code I don't know how to correctly make the logic to work this out.

Comment: I have read an answer from this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66372648/find-coordinates-of-the-lines-detected-by-the-canny-edge-detector) to use the code:
row_indexes, col_indexes = np.nonzero(edges) - to get the coordinates of the line that is why I tried to also use it. But I'm not sure if it's correct.

Comment: It's unclear. See [ask]. Where is your sentence for a question? What do you mean by 'I don't get the output in the console'? You didn't print anything. Anyway I don't recommend to iterate pixels. Find contours(outlines), select contours corresponding to wires, and get an average color of pixels in each region. See the official tutorial [Contour Features](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html).

Comment: np.count_nonzero() see docs at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html. Use axis= to specify whether to count rows or columns. It returns a count of non-zero pixels.